# Deleting a footer of a section VBA macro

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros

I am trying to find a macro expression to delete a footer of section 1 of my document. I see that this is a specific function that one can execute in Word Footer --> Remove footer, but if I want to record it using the macro recorder, nothing shows up.

Also looking through the documentation, it seems that

```
Activedocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)...
```

doesn't have a delete function. I feel there should be an easy solution to this and I just cant find it. Is there a more "light" solution than going over directly to something like this:

http://vba.relief.jp/word-macro-delete-all-headers-and-footers-active-document/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Delete
```

Comment: Exactly as I imagined. Did you just know that this method exists or did you find out the information in any way?

Comment: I just write this kind of code for a living ... I'm a Microsoft Word MVP ... it's what I do. :-)